# give focus to a panel that is not a child of the focused Window?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, focus

I'm working in Java to create an internal tool. The two consists of two `JPanels` which are anticipated to run on two separate screens.  I want to be able to click a `JButton` which is part of `JFrame A` which will send a keyboard action to `JFrame B`.

Unfortunately I can't seem to do this because `JFrame B` doesn't have the focus and I can't use any of the request `Focus` methods because `JFrame B` is not a child of the `Focus Window` (`JFrame A` is).

So how can I either give `JFrame B` focus despite it not being a child of the `Focus Window` or send `Keyboard Event`s to J`Frame B` that it will respond to without having focus?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Couldn't you just have the event listener (or button action) do whatever operation frame B would do if you were able to send a keyboard event to it?

Comment: If the two frames are in the same application, why send a keyboard event to the other frame?  Are you doing some kind of test automation?

Comment: yes this is for test automation.  I'm also using key events because I'm trying to reuse functionality inherited from the framework were using rather then reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is so hard to manage Focus between two [JFrames](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), better would be create only one [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) and other [Top-level Containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) would be [JDialogs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), create one/two [JDialog(s)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) and reuse that by removing all JComponents

basicaly it would be :

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

   @Override
     public void run() {
         someComponent.grabFocus();
         someComponent.requestFocus();//or inWindow depends if Swing or Awt
     }
});
```

but between two JFrames is things little bit complicated, just basic and uncompleted example (based on code from old.good.sun.forums.com)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PMDialog extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean modal = false;
    private WindowAdapter parentWindowListener;
    private Window owner;
    private JFrame blockedFrame = new JFrame("Blocked Frame");
    private JFrame noBlockedFrame = new JFrame("No Blocked Frame");

    public PMDialog() {
        noBlockedFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        noBlockedFrame.getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Test button") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Non blocked button pushed");
                /*if (blockedFrame.isVisible()) {
                noBlockedFrame.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                blockedFrame.setVisible(true);
                }*/
                noBlockedFrame.setVisible(true);
                blockedFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }));
        noBlockedFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        noBlockedFrame.setVisible(true);
        blockedFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        blockedFrame.getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Test Button") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                final PMDialog pmd = new PMDialog(blockedFrame, "Partial Modal Dialog", true);
                pmd.setSize(200, 100);
                pmd.setLocationRelativeTo(blockedFrame);
                pmd.getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Test button") {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        System.out.println("Blocked button pushed");
                        pmd.setVisible(false);
                        blockedFrame.setVisible(false);
                        noBlockedFrame.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }));
                pmd.setDefaultCloseOperation(PMDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                pmd.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("Returned from Dialog");
            }
        }));
        blockedFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        blockedFrame.setLocation(300, 0);
        blockedFrame.setVisible(false);
    }

    public PMDialog(JDialog parent, String title, boolean isModal) {
        super(parent, title, false);
        initDialog(parent, title, isModal);
    }

    public PMDialog(JFrame parent, String title, boolean isModal) {
        super(parent, title, false);
        initDialog(parent, title, isModal);
    }

    private void initDialog(Window parent, String title, boolean isModal) {
        owner = parent;
        modal = isModal;
        parentWindowListener = new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                if (isVisible()) {
                    System.out.println("Dialog.getFocusBack()");
                    getFocusBack();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void getFocusBack() {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        super.setVisible(false);
        super.pack();
        super.setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
        super.setVisible(true);
        super.toFront();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        owner.setEnabled(true);
        owner.setFocusableWindowState(true);
        super.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void hide() {
        owner.setEnabled(true);
        owner.setFocusableWindowState(true);
        super.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        boolean blockParent = (visible && modal);
        owner.setEnabled(!blockParent);
        owner.setFocusableWindowState(!blockParent);
        super.setVisible(visible);
        if (blockParent) {
            System.out.println("Adding listener to parent ...");
            owner.addWindowListener(parentWindowListener);
            try {
                if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
                    System.out.println("EventDispatchThread");
                    EventQueue theQueue = getToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
                    while (isVisible()) {
                        AWTEvent event = theQueue.getNextEvent();
                        Object src = event.getSource();
                        if (event instanceof ActiveEvent) {
                            ((ActiveEvent) event).dispatch();
                        } else if (src instanceof Component) {
                            ((Component) src).dispatchEvent(event);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("OUTSIDE EventDispatchThread");
                    synchronized (getTreeLock()) {
                        while (isVisible()) {
                            try {
                                getTreeLock().wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error from EDT ... : " + ex);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Removing listener from parent ...");
            owner.removeWindowListener(parentWindowListener);
            owner.setEnabled(true);
            owner.setFocusableWindowState(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setModal(boolean modal) {
        this.modal = modal;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PMDialog pMDialog = new PMDialog();
    }
}
```

EDIT: for How to adds Focus to the `JDialog` is there excelent Woodoo by camickr [Dialog Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) but [AncestorListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/AncestorListener.html) isn't my cup of Java and  too much abstract for me

Answer (score 2):

Is this a Swing GUI (you don't mention or add a tag to a gui library)?  If so, consider using [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which can be more flexible about focus compared with KeyListeners.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see how I could use key bindings.  The keys bindings I want already exist and developed for the Frame B.  this panel is actually part of a more complicated structure and is inheriting the functionality I'm trying to exploit from parts of the framework i can't touch.  My problem is not with binding keys but rather having a button press generate the keyEvents I need.  I know I could do this if I could just give my 'frame B' focus

Answer (score 2):

Nothing says you can't have one `Action` send a message to another. In this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel), `Enter` also needs to `Clear`, so it forwards the `ActionEvent`. Note also that each `NumberButton` binds two keystrokes to `Click`. In your case, you may have to to remove an existing binding and perhaps call [`toFront()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toFront%28%29) on the other window. Note the caveats that lend support to @mKorbel's answer.

Comment: hmmm looks like as I love your Kinetic..., my lazyness dosn't allows me wrote something most complex as this is, and my last brain cell died by run this code, +1

Comment: @mKorbel: Thanks!, Sorry about the brain cells. :-) I welcome any critical insights. Sadly, `KineticModel` is filled with evil, mutable `org.gcs.kinetic.Vector`.

Comment: that very good, if I said that I like that then some critic hmmm ... Atoms decrease on 5or6??th click returs initial numbers of Bals, bigger Atom has same kinetic acceleration as smaler Atom, maybe for someone glitering orange fat Border, but it does not disturb me