# How to make JFrame active (focused)?

Tags: java, swing

When dialog window displayed it does not focused if other window is active (i.e. you need to focus it by mouse pointer to be able to deal with it). How can I make a focus to displayed dialog?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GuiTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "test info", "test header",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        //frame.toFront();
        //frame.requestFocus();

        frame.dispose(); // When a frame is disposed, the exit action will be
                            // called.

    }

}
```

Comment: you need to call `setVisible(true)` on it

Comment: Presumably it's not the frame but the option pane that needs focus. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6626803/418556).

Comment: It looks like you are not using `frame` for anything here. Why do you have it in your code at all?

Comment: @Pshemo to make the dialog on top when other window is active and now the dialog need to be focused

Comment: What other window? If I remember correctly by default dialog box should be focused and on top of screen (`null` passed as first argument should ensure that it should be in center of desktop). If it is not happening then possibly you are doing something changing that behavior which you are not showing us. If that is the case then to help you properly we will need to see [mcve].

Comment: @Pshemo sorry there were an error, now `frame` is used and if you run it when other window is active than it will be clear that dialog is not active

Comment: did you followed this link :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus()

Comment: Sorry, but that code still makes dialog box on top and with focus (I can press space/enter and close it).

Comment: @Pshemo try to run it and right after that make any other window active. maybe you need increase Thread.sleep amount

Comment: @ElarbiMohamedAymen I used `frame.getRootPane().requestFocusInWindow();` but seems it does not change the behaviour

Comment: OK, I see the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog stops the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread) until the dialog is closed.

You could instead use another JFrame instead of a JOptionPane

```
package util;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GuiTest {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GuiTest window = new GuiTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);

                    Dialog d = new Dialog();
                    d.show();

                    window.frame.requestFocus();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GuiTest() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}

class Dialog extends JFrame {
    private JFrame frame;

    public void show() {

        if (frame == null) {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setTitle("Dialog");

            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            frame.add(new JTextField("Hello"));
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        }

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> try to run it and right after that make any other window active

Once a window loses focus you need to either:

1. click on the window to give it focus
2. Use the desktop manager to access the application. In Windows this is done by using Alt+Tab to cycle through open applications.

The problem is that only a JFrame is added to the desktop manager so if you want the ability to use Alt+Tab then you need to make the frame visible BEFORE showing the option pane.

Of course the JFrame will now be visible on the screen so you can use the setLocation(...) method with a negative value to hide the frame from the visible desktop.