# Automatically set focus on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, caret

Cant find an answer for this (or most likely Im not asking properly).

How can I set focus on `JTextField textfield1` as soon as my `JFrame` is initiated?
by focus I mean the user can start typing right away without having to click on the `JTextField`.

I tried `textfield1.setCaretPosition(0)` and `textfield1.moveCaretPosition(0)`, neither worked.

Also the focus stays on the submit button after clicking it (even if I call the above 2 after the click).

Comment: See [`JComponent.requestFocusInWindow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29).

Comment: Have you tried `textField1.requestFocusInWindow();`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fullscreen Swing frames not focusing correctly in Linux (Windows is fine)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667558/fullscreen-swing-frames-not-focusing-correctly-in-linux-windows-is-fine)

Comment: thanks, I tried searching on google but didnt think "focus" was the right word for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Focus is controlled in a number of ways in Swing, but in your case, the simplest might be to simply use [`JTextField#requestFocusInWindow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29)

It's a little off topic, but you might want to take a look at [How to use the a Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Comment: as soon as my JFrame is initiated? == wrapped into invokeLater

Answer (score 4):

A bit more fun than directly requesting the focus on the initial component is a custom FocusTraversalPolicy implementing a general mechanism to lookup/configure the default. The basic notions are already available in its api, having methods for returning the initial/defaultComponent, f.i.:

> public abstract Component getDefaultComponent(Container aContainer)
>
> Returns the default Component to focus. This Component will be the
>   first to receive focus when traversing down into a new focus traversal
>   cycle rooted at aContainer.

The default implementation returns the first component in the cycle, a custom implementation might look for a custom indicator, f.i. a client property. Simple usage would set that policy to the frame which has the marker in its contentPane, something like:

```
// a custom policy checking for the property
FocusTraversalPolicy policy = new LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy() {

    @Override
    public Component getDefaultComponent(Container aContainer) {
        if (aContainer instanceof JComponent) {
            JComponent parent = (JComponent) aContainer;
            if (parent.getClientProperty("defaultFocus") instanceof Component) {
                return (Component) parent.getClientProperty("defaultFocus");
            }
        }
        if (aContainer instanceof RootPaneContainer) {
            RootPaneContainer root = (RootPaneContainer) aContainer;
            JComponent parent = (JComponent) root.getContentPane();
            if (parent.getClientProperty("defaultFocus") instanceof Component) {
                return (Component) parent.getClientProperty("defaultFocus");
            }

        }
        return super.getDefaultComponent(aContainer);
    }

};
JFrame frame = ... // create  and fill
JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
frame.add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
// set the client property 
((JComponent) frame.getContentPane()).putClientProperty("defaultFocus", field);
// set the custom policy
frame.setFocusTraversalPolicy(policy);
```

A bit more elegant would be to use such a policy by default - that can be achieved by installing it as the default policy of the KeyboardFocusManager. With that in place the usage would be simplified to

- install the custom default once early in the application life-cycle
- mark the initial focus component (no need to manually set the frame's policy)

Code:

```
// very early in the application code
initializeDefaultFocusTraversalPolicy();

// default in any frame
JFrame frame = ... // create  and fill
JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
frame.add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
// set the client property 
((JComponent) frame.getContentPane())
    .putClientProperty(DelegatingFocusTraversalPolicy.DEFAULT_FOCUS_KEY, field);
```

Swing wouldn't be Swing it there weren't a catch, though:

- the frame's default policy is internally set on its instantiation - so it's not a big surprise that the keyboardFocusManager has to be configured *before* the frame is created
- the UIManager has its own ideas about the manager's default, in fact uncondionally configures it when the *very first* frame is created (which overwrites our own default)

The way out is to create a dummy frame and then set the policy:

```
public static void initializeDefaultFocusTraversalPolicy() {
    // a custom default policy is overwritten by the UIManager the
    // very first time it sees a top-level container created
    // it does so  unconditionally depending on a flag in LAFState
    // see UIManager.maybeInitializeFocusPolicy
    // so we tricks him into doing it for a fake frame
    new JFrame();
    // and set our custom default afterwards
    FocusTraversalPolicy p = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
         .getDefaultFocusTraversalPolicy();
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
         .setDefaultFocusTraversalPolicy(new CustomFocusTraversalPolicy(p));
}

/**
 * Basically the same custom policy as the ad-hoc above, just with
 * delegating 
 */
public static class CustomFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy {
    public static final String DEFAULT_FOCUS_KEY = "defaultFocus";
    private FocusTraversalPolicy delegate;

    public CustomFocusTraversalPolicy(FocusTraversalPolicy delegate) {
        this.delegate = Contract.asNotNull(delegate, "the delegate must not be null");
    }

    @Override
    public Component getDefaultComponent(Container container) {
        if (container instanceof JComponent) {
            JComponent parent = (JComponent) container;
            if (parent.getClientProperty(DEFAULT_FOCUS_KEY) instanceof Component) {
                return (Component) parent.getClientProperty(DEFAULT_FOCUS_KEY);
            }
        }
        if (container instanceof RootPaneContainer) {
            RootPaneContainer root = (RootPaneContainer) container;
            JComponent parent = (JComponent) root.getContentPane();
            if (parent.getClientProperty(DEFAULT_FOCUS_KEY) instanceof Component) {
                return (Component) parent.getClientProperty(DEFAULT_FOCUS_KEY);
            }

        }
        return delegate.getDefaultComponent(container);
    }
    @Override
    public Component getComponentAfter(Container aContainer,
            Component aComponent) {
        return delegate.getComponentAfter(aContainer, aComponent);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getComponentBefore(Container aContainer,
            Component aComponent) {
        return delegate.getComponentBefore(aContainer, aComponent);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getFirstComponent(Container aContainer) {
        return delegate.getFirstComponent(aContainer);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getLastComponent(Container aContainer) {
        return delegate.getLastComponent(aContainer);
    }
}
```